# CodeIgniter controller functions not triggered

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

In CodeIgniter, my url `someurl.com/test/` will not execute anything inside the controller class. Please take a look and tell me if there's something you can think of that might prevent the execution of the CI_Controller here or where I should look.

For example the following

```
some.testurl.com/test/hi/Bob
some.testurl.com/test
some.testurl.com/test/hi
```

all show:

```
Above class
Below class
```

**EDIT:**
I believe my issue is with how I'm trying to run two separate applications. One is at `testurl.com` and the other is `some.testurl.com` where the directory for `some.testurl.com` is a subfolder of the directory where `testurl.com` is held. What's the right way to do this that they both work?

Update:
Moving the subdomain outside the other CodeIgniter application's directory hasn't changed the behavior in any way. The CodeIgniter controller does not do anything.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

    echo "Above class<br>";

    class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mod_login');
        $this->load->helper('date');

        }
//443 replace with 482
    function index() {
        echo "Index function";
    }

    function hi($name)
    {
        echo "Hi".$name."!";
    }
}

echo "Below class<br>";
?>
```

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|common|ico|database_backup|images|img|js|scripts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

1. Error reporting is enabled already and no errors are triggered. Environment is defined as development on the index file.

Comment: Your controller file is fine .I am guessing you might have errors either on helper file or model file. check those files too. You can enable error reporting and check for errors.

Comment: Is this working **someurl.com/index.php/test/** ?

Comment: Hi Bugfixer. When I try that I get a CI generated  404 error.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a **mod_rewrite** issue. Check your php info to see if the module is installed and running on the **apache** server.

If there is, check you httpd.conf file at `<Directory "C:/PATH/TO/YOUR/APP">` directive, where it should exist `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: Thanks for the time, but mod_rewrite is already working fine.

Answer (score 0):

A missing curly bracket in database.php broke the whole application without triggering an error message. I'm sorry because no one could ever guess it. It's not the type of error I expected to cause this problem because I verified that environment was development and I triggered lots of other errors in my quest to fix this.

If someone else runs into this, just know it could be a simple error in any of the config files.

Thanks everyone.